# Vanilla JS nested fetch with youtube data API

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I've just started learning JS a week ago so I'm pretty new to everything in there, and for my first project I have to write in Vanilla JS. The project is to make a fake YouTube app using YouTube Data API.

Here's the code that I'm having a problem with (I want to continue with rest of the code only after the data2 function is finnished):

```
function generateResults(data){
        pageTokens.push(data.nextPageToken);
        data.items.forEach((item) => {
            let thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
            let title = item.snippet.title.substring(0, 60);
            let channel = item.snippet.channelTitle;
            let vid = item.id.videoId;
            let viewCount = 0;

            const data2 = async () => {
                const response = await fetch (`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=${vid}&key=${API_KEY}
                &part=statistics`)
                const json = await response.json();
                viewCount = json.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
            }
            data2();
            
            videosHTML += `
            <article class="art" data-key="${vid}">
                <img src="${thumb}" alt="" class="thumb">
                <div class="details">
                    <h4>${title}</h4>
                    <p>${channel}</p>
                    <p>${viewCount} - Date</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            `;
        })
        document.getElementById('videos').innerHTML = videosHTML;
        videosHTML="";
}
```

In this part I'm making video thumbnails and I'm using 2 API's to do so. With the first API (which is not included in this code) I'm getting the search list of all the videos, and then in this function (generateResults) I'm using that fetched data to call the second API to give me specific information on each video (I need the view count). But because fetch is async the viewCount doesn't get included and it stays 0. I've tried to make generateResults and the arrow function in the forEach loop async as well but then innerHTML part doesn't execute at all and I'm getting no thumbnails at all.

As I've said I'm pretty new to all of this so sorry if it's something really obvious but I've spent 10+ hrs searching for answers on the internet and nothing works. Ty in advance!

P.S.: The data2 function is working, I've tried console.log("viewCount") and it properly displays the viewCount but it probably only executes after the innerHTML part is already executed.

Comment: You can use the `article[data-key]' to find the item corresponding of each data2 response, and append the value.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I've said I'm very new to all of this so I'm no sure how to do that or how to formulate a question on google to figure out how to do that, could you be a bit more specific? How do I get to the ${viewCount} variable and change it? I thought it becomes a string once it becomes HTML code.

Comment: "started learning JS a week ago" and is already doing async API calls and manipulating the DOM?? In my first week I could barely do an `alert` haha. Good job!

Comment: Ty @BrunoMonteiro! I've tried your solution as well but for some reason it only displays the html code on the webpage, idk why's that, but @Bazaim 's code is working so the problem is solved, do I need to close the question or something? It's my first question on stackoverflow so I'm not sure what to do now

Comment: Glad to know you find a solution! You should mark @Bazaim answer as accepted, in the little green checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer

```
function generateResults(data){
    pageTokens.push(data.nextPageToken);
    data.items.forEach((item) => {
        let thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
        let title = item.snippet.title.substring(0, 60);
        let channel = item.snippet.channelTitle;
        let vid = item.id.videoId;
        let viewCount = 0;

        const data2 = async () => {
            const response = await fetch (`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=${vid}&key=${API_KEY}
            &part=statistics`)
            const json = await response.json();
            viewCount = json.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
            
            document.querySelector(`#videos article[data-key="${vid}"] .view-count`).innerText = viewCount;
        }
        data2();
        
        
        videosHTML += `
        <article class="art" data-key="${vid}">
            <img src="${thumb}" alt="" class="thumb">
            <div class="details">
                <h4>${title}</h4>
                <p>${channel}</p>
                <p><span class="view-count">Loading</span> - Date</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        `;
    })
    document.getElementById('videos').innerHTML = videosHTML;
    videosHTML="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction. You can move the code that generates your HTML (`videosHTML`) inside your `data2` function, so it will wait for your async call to return.

You can also use `append` to add more HTML content to your videos `div`, so you don't need to keep cleaning the `videosHTML` variable. In fact, you can create that variable inside your `data2` function.

Here is the updated code:

```
function generateResults(data){
  pageTokens.push(data.nextPageToken);
  data.items.forEach((item) => {
    let thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
    let title = item.snippet.title.substring(0, 60);
    let channel = item.snippet.channelTitle;
    let vid = item.id.videoId;
    let viewCount = 0;

    const data2 = async () => {
        const response = await fetch (`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=${vid}&key=${API_KEY}
        &part=statistics`)
        const json = await response.json();
        viewCount = json.items[0].statistics.viewCount;

        const videosHTML = `
        <article class="art" data-key="${vid}">
            <img src="${thumb}" alt="" class="thumb">
            <div class="details">
                <h4>${title}</h4>
                <p>${channel}</p>
                <p>${viewCount} - Date</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        `;
        document.getElementById('videos').append(videosHTML);
    }
    data2();
  })
}
```